# Как показывать сайт в цветовой схеме, которую предпочитает пользователь?

Tags: javascript, css

Есть сайт с двумя темами оформления: светлой и тёмной. Например, как [Башорг](https://bash.im/) или [документация Docker](https://docs.docker.com/). Темы реализованы через класс на теге `<html>` или `<body>`, CSS для тем описаны через этот класс, переключатель темы меняет его на противоположный.

Можно ли при первой загрузке страницы определять с помощью JS/CSS, какую тему предпочитает пользователь, и автоматически переключаться на эту тему?

Предпочтение пользователя может быть известно из настроек ОС (такое есть в последней версии macOS и Win10), либо из выбранной цветовой схемы браузера.

В ответе хотелось бы видеть инфу о том, в каких браузерах и их версиях поддерживается решение.

---

Решения на стороне клиента вроде плагинов для браузера не подходят. Куки с сохранённым выбором темы тоже не подходят. Задача — ни одного раза не выжечь сетчатку пользователю, который открыл наш сайт ночью в тёмной комнате.

«Как переключать тему через JS» —  не вопрос, это уже реализовано в переключателе темы. Вопрос в том, как в JS/CSS узнать, какую тему предпочитает пользователь.

Comment: Ещё интересно то же самое про специальные темы для людей с ограничениями по зрению: контрастные, с увеличенными шрифтами, с конкретной палитрой.

Comment: А что собственно трудного ? У вас есть **JS**, у вас есть **CSS**, остается лишь приделать класс к **body** и наследоваться от него. Определяете стилистику сайта, оформляете как обычно. А затем добавляете **body** тегу какой-нибудь класс - **theme-dark**. В стилях уже и пишите **body.theme-dark { background-color: black; }** и т.д. А с помощью **JS** вы просто меняете класс у **body** и сохраняете в **localStorage** .

Comment: @MoloF сложность во втором абзаце... чтобы не использовать localStorage)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME а по-другому и никак, JS не даст куда-то сохранить кроме как в **Cookie** или **localStorage**, а из них двух приятнее все же будет локальное хранилище.

Comment: @MoloF не надо быть таким категоричным, есть еще варианты сохранить инфу у клиента =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ поведаете о них? Я правда кроме этих двух не знаю куда еще можно сохранить данные.. Ведь речь идет только о фронте как я понял. И сохранить куда-то в другое место не представляет возможным, но я с радостью послушаю еще варианты, возможно я чего-то нового не знаю

Comment: @MoloF https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/IndexedDB например, еще https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

Comment: _Решения на стороне клиента вроде плагинов для браузера не подходят._ - эм, а какие подходят тогда?

Comment: например: [How to detect a user’s preferred color scheme in JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-detect-a-users-preferred-color-scheme-in-javascript-ec8ee514f1ef/)

Comment: Эм, а для кого в последние месяцы написали кучу статей? https://t.me/webstandards_ru поищите тут

Comment: @StrangerintheQ indexeddb тот же localStorage вид сбоку для нужд сохранения одного флага

Comment: @AlexeyTen я и не предлагаю его использовать в данном конкретном случае =)

Comment: @MoloF переключение темы через `body.theme-dark` уже есть. Вопрос в том как при первой загрузке страницы выяснить предпочитаемую тему и включить именно её.

Comment: @Grundy ага, я видел эту статью. Решение через `prefers-color-scheme` интересное, но из статьи непонятно, поддерживается ли оно уже в браузерах, и как его совместить с произвольным переключением темы.

Comment: @Grundy и я надеюсь, что придёт кто-нибудь шарящий во фронтенде и напишет подробный ответ. ;)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, там ссылка на caniuse была - судя по нему - последние браузеры кроме edge ,ie

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, вариантов реализации много..
Если хотите использовать JS/JQ, то лучше всего воспользоваться [локальным хранилищем](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

---

Допустим, наш дизайн будет работать следующим образом:

У тега `body` будет класс, который отвечает за цвет темы, далее в CSS прописываются стили под разные темы.

Задача:
Переключать и сохранять выбранную тему у пользователя.

Всю будет выглядеть следующим образом: (**Пример на jQuery**)
(Описание работы скрипта - комментарии в коде)

```js
$('body').addClass('theme-light'); // для демо, чтобы сниппет соответствовал задаче)

// Это сохранение выбранной темы
$('#theme').on('change', function(){ // при выборе темы..
  let val = $(this).val(); // получим в переменную атрибут value
  $('body') // обратимся к body
    .attr('class', 'theme-'+val); // добавим выбранную тему с префиксом 'theme-'
    
  // Далее сохраняем значение в localStorage
  //localStorage.setItem('theme', val);
  // Но я её закоментил, ибо в сниппете она работать не будет.
});

// Сохранение мы написали, но если обновить страницу, то дизайн слетит, по этому пишем ещё код, который будет брать значение из локального хранилища и ставить его..
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  let theme = localStorage('theme') || 'light'; // Получаем значение из хранилища, если его нет, то используем 'light' как дефолтное.
  // P.s. это код тоже не будет работать в сниппете.
  // А дальше как и выше
  $('body') // обращаемся к body
    .attr('class', 'theme-'+theme); // ставим класс с префиксом.
    
  // ещё для красоты можно сделать так
  $('#theme option:selected') // обратимся к селектору с темой
    .prop('selected', false); // у "выбранного" уберём  "выбор"
  $('#theme option[value="'+theme+'"]') // найдём так же тот option с сохранённой темой
    .prop('selected', true); // и поставим "выбор" на него.
  
});
```

```css
/* Общие стили, желательно без "цветов" */
#theme {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

/* Светлая тема */
.theme-light { /* Это цвет фона для body */
  background: #aaa;
}

/* Остальным частям дизайна придётся прописывать стили аналогично ниже */
.theme-light #theme {
  border-color: #666;
  background: #ccc;
}

.theme-light h1 {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
}

/* Тёмная тема */
.theme-dark {
  background: #222;
}

.theme-dark #theme {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background: #666;
  color: #ddd;
}

.theme-dark h1 {
  color: #ddd;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="theme">
  <option value="light" selected>Светлая</option>
  <option value="dark">Тёмная</option>
</select>

<h1>Ваш сайт</h1>
```

Comment: Спасибо за классный ответ! К сожалению, это ответ не на мой вопрос. Вопрос предполагает, что сами темы и их переключение уже реализовано. "Получаем значение из хранилища, если его нет, то используем 'light' как дефолтное" —  а нужно как дефолтное использовать то, что выбрано в настройках операционной системы или браузера. Как это сделать?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, те сайты, что указанны в вопросе предоставляют похожий функционал что указан в моём ответе. По поводу "дефолтный, который выбран в настройках ОС или браузера".. Насчёт ОС, думаю без стороннего ПО не обойтись, насчёт браузера.. Может и есть какое-то API, вот только вряд ли его предоставят все браузеры.

Comment: «те сайты, что указанны в вопросе предоставляют похожий функционал» — и вопрос был не о том, как реализовать этот функционал. Он уже реализован. Теперь нужно при первой загрузке узнать, какая тема выбрана у пользователя в ОС и включить её. `localStorage` тут не поможет, потому что это первая загрузка.

Answer (score 0):

1. Выясниение у системы или браузера, какую именно цветовую схему предпочитает пользователь, до сих пор толком не реализовано. На нынешний момент это умеет пара браузеров, да и то не везде.
2. ответ дан в англоязычной части: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840168/how-to-detect-if-the-os-is-in-dark-mode-in-browsers
3. для справки сходите сюда: https://medium.com/@jonas_duri/enable-dark-mode-with-css-variables-and-javascript-today-66cedd3d7845

Comment: _All major browsers are supporting dark mode now, except: IE, Edge_ как-то не очень вяжется с _На нынешний момент это умеет пара браузеров, да и то не везде._